# Filling a form in JSP with ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, jakarta-ee, select, fill

I know this kind of questions has already been asked, but I totally am a newbie with Ajax and JavaScript.
I have a field (`codigo_caso`) which I need to be **the launcher for the form filling**

`<input id="codigo_caso" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="codigo_caso" value=""/>`

I have to retrieve 4 variables after loosing focus on that field (or 1 variable if the other 4 are empty)
And the big problem after retrieving those 4 variables is how to work well with them.

**JSP Web Page --> Script**
This is the fragment i **copied from the internet and modified to receive ONE field**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#codigo_caso").blur(function() {
        var cod = $(this).val();
        var dataString1 = {"codigo":cod};
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "otros/codigoCasoDependienteNuevaTarea.jsp",
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataString1,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $(".linea_equipo").response("linea_equipo");
                $("#selectArea").filter(function() {
                    return $(this).response("id_area") === response("area");
                }).prop('selected', true);
                $(".listaCentros").response("nombre_centro");
                $("#listaRolNuevaTarea").filter(function() {
                    return $(this).response("id_rol") === response("rol");
                }).prop('selected', true);
            }
        });
     });
  });
```

This is my JSP file launching the SQL [where i need to recover several variables]. **I need to know how to return these 3 fields to my previous JSP**

**JSP FILE --> otros/codigoCasoDependienteNuevaTarea.jsp**

```
String linea = "", centro = "", error = "No existe el caso indicado";
int area, rol;
Connection conex = (Connection) session.getAttribute("conexion");
Statement st = conex.createStatement();
String sql = "";
String cod = request.getParameter("codigo").toString();
if (cod != null && !cod.isEmpty() && !cod.equals("0")) {
    sql = "SELECT t1.linea_equipo,t1.id_rol, t2.id_area,t2.nombre_centro "
            + " FROM gen_casos_prisma t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN gen_centros t2 ON "
            + " t1.id_centro = t2.id_centro "
            + " WHERE "
            + " t1.CODIGO_CASO =  " + cod;
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    rs.beforeFirst();
    if (rs.next()) {
        linea = rs.getString("linea_equipo");
        area = rs.getInt("id_area");
        centro = rs.getString("nombre_centro");
        rol = rs.getInt("id_rol");

        JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
        j.put("linea_equipo", linea);
        j.put("id_area", area+"");
        j.put("nombre_centro", centro);
        j.put("id_rol", rol+"");


    } else {
        /* return variable error */
    }
    response.setContentType("application/json");

 }
```

The next step after knowing how to receive these fields is to know what to do with them. i know how can i place `linea_equipo` in a text-field [with the code I posted in the script above the JAVA code] but i also need to set as "selected" one option in each of these lists (two are dropdown lists and the other is a datalist) taking into account that they are already filled; just need to place selected attribute in the value that matches the field that the form must receive from this ajax-jsp thing. 
(selectArea - `id_area`, listaCentrosDeArea - `nombre_centro`, listaRolNuevaTarea - `id_rol`)

```
<select id="selectArea" >
    <%out.print(f.getSelectAreas(conex));%>
</select>
<datalist id="listaCentrosDeArea" id="datalist1">
    <% //out.print(f.selectCentrosNOUser(conex, updateTarea));%>
</datalist>
<select id="listaRolNuevaTarea" name="rol">
    <% out.print(f.selectRolesNoUser(conex));%>
</select>
```

Sorry if it seems a bit tricky or heavy, but I've been requested to do this and I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing

```
success: function(html) {
     ("#linea_equipo").val(html);
}
```

you are returning the value to the JSP, so just make sure that all the elements that you want filled in have an id like `linea_equipo`

Answer (score 0):

In the success part of your code you can write the logic to populate data to your form.

```
success: function(response)
{

$("#ID").val("value");//find these value from your response
// if your response is JSON you can replace value like response.key    
}
```

[see what json is](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)

For selecting a drop down by jQuery use

```
$('#dropdownid').val('selectedvalue');
```

//========
code to return response as json in java servlet

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(jsonobject.toString());
```

Comment: and if it's not a json, how do i return all 4 values? as an array?

Comment: See what you are expecting in response from server. .
use dataType in the ajax method syntax to tell what format you are expecting. .

in success you can alert response

Comment: I think it is easier to use JSON as response I have added code to return response as JSON.

Comment: Ok, I'm not working in a servlet but in a JSP file. So how do i return the json object?